# Do supertables produce bottlenecks?

Tags: postgresql, performance, schema, polymorphic-associations

There are several alternatives to using polymorphic associations and one of them is to use the so-called "concrete supertable". From my point of view, this is the neatest solution and is pretty easy to implement so I use it almost always. But now consider the following schema as an example:

We have statuses, photos, videos, links, and albums. All of them share pretty much the same attributes, let's say: author_id, owner_id, and description/body. They also share most of its associations: can be commented, voted, shared...and so on.

So it makes sense to me to have a supertable "posts" containing the shared attributes between tables. Furthermore, its associated tables can use the post_id as its foreign key, tidy!

The problem I see here is that almost every query to the children tables implies querying the parent supertable, e.g: create a status implies create a post, update a photo implies update its post, select a user statuses implies joining on the post table, an so on.

Considering a system with a lot of concurrency, isn't this going to produce a bottleneck?

EDIT: I think I have a better question that resumes the background of my first question: There's a performance difference between concurrently querying two different tables and querying the same table (but different rows of this table)?

Comment: Why getting a video comments imply joining to the posts? I would guess that you only need `comments JOIN videos`. But joining is not going to be a problem in my opinion. You may try to have the supertable as narrow as possible and only use it for INSERT (or perhaps DELETE) and rarely if never UPDATE.

Comment: PostgreSQL's inheritance features may be interesting to you.

Comment: @ypercube You're absolutely right. Corrected.

Comment: @CraigRinger I know about PostgreSQL's inheritance, but I would like to stick to a more general solution from a SQL POV. Just in case, the question scenario is just a virtual example, not a real concrete case.